# Does this webservice work for android as well?

Tags: android, json, web-services, titanium

```
 https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/demos/KitchenSink/Resources/examples/soap.js
```

I have tested this for iphone that is working fine but not fine with android.Please help.

Comment: what you required, the above link will just navigate to github? do you want to ask the web service used in the github is helpful or not or else you directly used above link as ws url

Comment: I think we use webservices for making our data common on web.It must run on android.

Comment: Thanks Nagaraj, actually the service is on my service and that is in PHP the link you shared is consuming a service written in asp.net please share if you used PHP web service and sent parameters along as well.Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the web service url used in the above link example in android also. The Web service shown there can be used in many ways. you can do soap parsing or else you do xml parsing too. if you want to it via xml parsing then use the below link

http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx/ConversionRate?FromCurrency=USD&ToCurrency=INR

in which you need to replace USD (here us dollar) and INR (Indian rupees) with your required conversions.